# How to load records from Setting table of NopCommerce v3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject, autofac, nopcommerce

I'm trying to use NopCommerce v3.5 and trying to replace Autofac with Ninject v3.2. I've been searching how NopCommerce load records from Setting table, it's still not clear. And if ever, I want to load the settings using Ninject. Thank you for any help.

Here's a sample code in Nop.web.Framework.DependencyRegistrar.cs

```
builder.RegisterType<SettingService>().As<ISettingService>()
    .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<ICacheManager>("nop_cache_static"))
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterSource(new SettingsSource());
```

Comment: I'm curious why you want to replace Autofac? Is there something that it doesn't give you that Ninject does?

Comment: @Steven I already have a custom controller factory (NinjectControllerFactory), and a NinjectDependencyResolver as my default dependency resolver. I'm now working on Setting and Caching.

Comment: @DavidG It's just, I'm not used to Autofac. I've been using Ninject, but I'm still not in intermediate level when it comes to Ninject, I think :)

Comment: I would suggest to stick with Autofac for two reasons: 1- It's actually really easy to use. 2- When Nop release an update that fixes a critical security flaw, you will be stuck on an old version.

Comment: I agree with @DavidG: Stick with Autofac for the NopCommerce internals. But this doesn't mean though that you are forced to using Autofac to resolve your own classes, or even when you do, I would advice keeping the framework's configuration and your application's configuration separated. For your application components, use the IOC container that suits you best.

Comment: But I'm already here :(  Also, this way I tend to explore deeper into the NopCommerce's architecture. I find it amazing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll try to explain it as well as I can.

According to [Autofac's docs](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced/registration-sources.html), `RegisterSource` allows you to register factories for classes that you don't know about or have considered. It will really late bind the types with the rules that provide them.

How does this apply here?

When you require an instance of a class such as `LoggerSettings` from the container, autofac will check all the rules you have declared at the different dependency registrars that nopCommerce has, and it will ask the registration source: Hey! I need an instance of LoggerSettings, do you know something about this? The RegistrationSource checks it and says "Yes, it implements `ISettings`, here you have the injection rule for it (in this case a lambda that retrieves the settings instance from a generic repository), keep it, next time you won't need to ask". Note that it will return the instantiation rule for the type, not the instance itself.

As an alternative, maybe you could do it crawling all assemblies, but for a large system with plugins like this, it would be a pain. You could also register each particular class, but in this case it is not doable.

To see it working, set a couple of breakpoints at the two methods of SettingsSource and inside the delegate and start the project.

To do it with Ninject you will need to replicate this behaviour.